# concatenating two dataframes that are created in a loop

Tags: python, concatenation

I have written a function that scrapes data using snscrape. However I am not sure how to solve the following issue:

- I want to scrape data from all 50 states of USA. Thus I have a custom function named tweets that scrapes the data with the parameters that I have chosen and I have another dataframe that contains the states which has the following form

```
states_df 

USA_state_code           latitude             longitude        usa_state
AK                         63.58               -154.49          Alaska
AL                         32.31                -86.90          Alabama
...                         ...                  ...              ...
```

- I want to create a loop that takes all the usa state names, the latitude and the longitude so I can use it as an input for my tweets function
- My tweet function will return a dataframe(100,2) of the following form

```
date                  message
01/01/2022            the message that I scraped
..                     ...
```

- And take this dataframe each time and append it to a big dataframe that has the following form

```
date                  message                                    state
01/01/2022            the message that I scraped                 Alaska
...                       ...                                      ...
01/01/2022            100th the message that I scraped           Alaska
01/01/2022            101th the message that I scraped           Alabama
...                               ...                               ...
```

(don t mind the message, I just wrote it like that to show that the states will be added).
However, I am a bit confused on the syntax of that loop and how to concatenate the dataframe that is returned everytime

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the full scope of the question, but for the first part you should be able to use `df.iterrows()`. This is an iterator that will return a tuple of the row.

```py
for row in states_df.iterrows():
    state_code = row[1]
    lat = row[2]
    long = row[3]
    state_name = row[4]
    ....
    df = tweets(state_code,lat,long,...) # no idea how your tweets function actually works
```

For the other question on concating, I would make an empty dataframe of the shape you want and then concat these in that loop.

```py
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','message','state']) #or whatever your columns should be
for row in states_df.iterrows():
    ...
    df = tweets(...)
    pd.concat([main_df,df])
```

This will just add the new rows onto `main_df` each time.